# Select contenteditable span

Tags: javascript, html

I have a multiple `<span>` with `contenteditable`, I am trying to programmatically "select" a `<span>` and force into editable mode. But it seems I am having a lot of trouble doing this.

With `<input>` I can use

```
element.select();
```

but a `<span>` obviously does not have this method.

I need to use `<span>` has the content is designed to be copy/pasted out with a bunch of uneditable content which `<input>` does not allow the mix and matching when selecting all the code.

I could do a bunch of funky work with putting the content of the `<input>` into a hidden `<span>` within the content that is being copied/pasted out so it could fake that it would work, but I have everything else working as expected and it is almost a finished product and do not wish to rewrite everything as the only problem I have is knowing how to **select** the next `<span>` when necessary.

PS: prefer no jQuery for this question.

Comment: Give the span an ID and fake a click - `document.getElementById('myID').click();`

Comment: I am afraid this does not work.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so we can test

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f943gh93/ notice it goes red, with no edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `element.focus();`

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gz4mpm3p/)

[Pure JS Version](https://jsfiddle.net/gz4mpm3p/1/)

Comment: @Shubham, that seems to be pure JS to me, unless he has edited the answer before I seen it.

Comment: Yes. I took my words back +1 for pure Js. 
I belieave `contenteditable="true"` this is the key thing to set here.